# Once You Free() a Struct, the Struct’s Pointer is Still Active?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, free

I have a new C program written on Ubuntu, compiled with GCC.  (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1))  My code `malloc()`’s and `free()`’s many, many, many structs on-the-fly.  After my program runs for several hours, it crashes with this message:

```
double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I’m assuming that “double free” means that my code is calling `free()` on a previously-`malloc()`ed struct at least twice.  That’s very possible.  My code creates many different structs depending on the input, and despite my best intentions, it could be trying to `free()` something twice.

So I am working with valgrind to find the problem, but another solution occurred to me.  Why can’t my code look at a pointer to a struct and know if the struct has been `free()`’ed or not?  I tried to design a solution.  Consider:

```
typedef struct MeStruct{
        int a, b, c;
}me;

me* buildMe( int a, int b, int c ){
        me* ret = malloc(sizeof(me));
        ret->a = a;     ret->b = b;     ret->c = c;
        return ret;
}

void printMe( me* me1 ){
        printf("------------------------------\n");
        printf("printMe() :: pointer address is: %p\n", me1);
        if( me1 == NULL ){
                printf("NULL\n");
        } else {
                printf( "ME struct :: %d %d %d\n", me1->a, me1->b, me1->c );
        }
        printf("------------------------------\n");
}

void freeMe( me* me1 ){
        printf("Calling freeStuff()\n");
        if( me1 != NULL ){
                free( me1 );
                me1 = NULL;      // DOES THIS DO ANYTHING???
        }
}

int main( int argc, char **argv ){

        me* me1 = buildMe( 1, 2, 3 );

        printMe( me1 );
        freeMe( me1 );      // First attempt to free( me1 )
        printMe( me1 );
        freeMe( me1 );      // Second attempt to free( me1 )
        printf("END OF PROGRAM.\n");
        return 1;
}
```

So at first, I thought this was pretty clever.  When a struct is `free()`’ed, the code sets the struct’s pointer to NULL, thus giving a way to detect if the struct is valid or not later.  But the line marked with “`DOES THIS DO ANYTHIING???`” seems to do nothing.  Here’s the output:

```
------------------------------
printMe() :: pointer address is: 0x555a71097260
ME struct :: 1 2 3
------------------------------
Calling freeStuff()
------------------------------
printMe() :: pointer address is: 0x555a71097260
ME struct :: 0 0 3
------------------------------
Calling freeStuff()
END OF PROGRAM.
```

So the second call to `printMe()` is interesting here.  At this point, the struct has been `free()`’ed, meaning that the chunk of memory on the heap that was allocated for the struct is no longer allocated.  And yet, the struct’s pointer has not changed, and perhaps I can even see some of the original data?  (`me1->c` is still value “3”)

So it looks like my scheme won’t work, at least not on this compiler.  A few questions nag me.  First, ***WHY*** doesn’t this work?  Why isn’t the value of the pointer NULL after the call to `freeMe()`?  And why didn’t the second call to `freeMe()` crash the program?  After all, the second call tries to `free()` the struct a second time.

Any thoughts or criticism is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:  I fixed a copy/paste error, where the "return 1;" was placed before the "printf("END OF PROGRAM.\n");" call in `main()`.

Comment: Free() does not affect the pointer, only the memory object that it points to.

Comment: C functions are pass-by-value.  Calling `freeMe(p)` cannot affect the caller's value of `p`. You could write a version that passes by reference and call it as `my_free(&p)`, or a macro, but it would only give you a false sense of security as there could be other copies of the pointer that would not change.

Comment: @NateEldredge Hmm...  true.  So the line that sets "me1 = NULL;" is affecting the pointer WITHIN THE FUNCTION, but not the pointer declared back in main() ?

Comment: @Pete yes, that's correct.

Comment: @PascalGetreuer  Ahhhh...  Yes, that makes a world of sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

A pointer is just a number/memory address. Once you `free()` it, it retains its value and is still a pointer, albeit one that no longer points to valid data. That memory it points to may now be used by the memory allocator for subsequent calls to `malloc()`.

You may still see stale values from your struct after you've freed that memory because `free()` is not obligated to zero out that the freed memory. But you should no longer be accessing it. If you make subsequent calls to `malloc()` and populate your heap with more data, you'll likely see your data being overwritten.

As Nate Eldredge explained, C functions pass arguments by value. Your pointer is not being modified for the same reason that `v` in the following example remains unchanged after a call to `foo()`:

```c
void foo(int a) {
    a = 3; // only modifies a in this local context
}
void bar(int *p) {
    *p = 3; // modifies what p is pointing to, i.e. v
}

int main(void) {
    int v = 1;
    foo(v);         // v is copied to foo
    assert(v == 1); // v remains untouched
    bar(&v);        // pointer to v is passed to bar
    assert(v == 3); // which is successfully modified
    return 0;
}
```

The pointer value you have passed in to `freeMe()` is just like the integer value in this example, except it happens to point to some memory address.

Note that a double free induces *undefined behavior*, so `free()` is allowed to do whatever it wants when called upon the same address for the second time --- it doesn't *necessarily* have to report the double free error.

Comment: Thanks for writing.  You're right about the locality of the pointer in main() versus in a called function; I'd forgotten that from my C classes.  BTW, I made a copy/paste error and put the "return 1;" line too early in main().  I've since fixed the error.  THank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a permanent `NULL` value to the pointer, you need to pass the memory address of the pointer, not the pointer.

```
void freeMe1(char *temp) {
    free(temp);  // will free memory; its effect is persistent
    temp = NULL; // will assign NULL to pointer but its effect is local only
}

void freeMe2(char **temp) {
    free(*temp);  // will free memory; its effect is persistent
    *temp = NULL; // will assign NULL to pointer and its effect is persistent
}

...
int main {
    char *str = malloc(...);
    ...
    ...
    freeMe1(str);  // str is not nullified
    freeMe2(&str); // str is nullified
    ...
}
```