# What happens to a pointer after what it's been pointing to has been freed

Tags: c, free

Background info: My program involves creating a hash table and one of my functions is `free_hash(struct hash_table *table)`.

`struct hash_table *table` points to an array of `struct hash_entry` pointers. To test my `free_hash` function in `main` I have a `void *test_free = what`. the declaration and initialization for `what` is `hash_table *what = new_hash(array_size)`.

this is `struct hash_table *new_hash()` it returns a function that returns a pointer to a new initialized `struct hash_table`.

My question: After freeing `what`, eg.`free_hash(what)`, what happens to `test_free`. What is the address of it/the value of what it is pointing at. And is there any other way I can make sure that `what` has been destructed/freed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mcve], not just a description of what your code does.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. Showing code is a lot more helpful than describing it. Please [edit] your question to include a full program we can compile and run ourselves.

Comment: [Maybe see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63874170/once-you-free-a-struct-the-struct-s-pointer-is-still-active).

Answer (score 3):

`test_free` and `what` are pointers. The value they have is basically an address. And you assigned the same address to both of them. Nothing happens to either variable once you free that to which they point.

Once you do, the pointers are deemed to be indeterminate, so it becomes undefined behaviour to deference either one. But there's nothing in either variable that indicates this. The onus is on the programmer to ensure no attempts is made to access a freed structure.

As for checking if everything was properly freed, there's `-fsanitize=address`, `valgrind`, etc.

Comment: “Nothing happens to either variable once you free that to which they point” is incorrect. C 2018 6.2.4. 2 says they become indeterminate.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: [Valgrind is supported on Linux, OS X, and Solaris, plus unofficial ports to some other systems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind#Platforms_supported)

Comment: @Eric Postpischil You are wrong, and I stand by what I said. A pointer becoming indeterminate does not result in any change to the variable. I already mentioned there are things you can no longer do with the pointer. The point which you somehow missed is that since nothing happens to `what`, `test_free` isn't missing out on anything. The OP appeared to believe it did. You seem to have somehow missed the point of the question too, cause the answer to the OP's question is at best implied by your Answer.

Comment: @ikegami I think the point is that "becoming indeterminate" implies *more* than just "it becomes undefined behavior to dereference".  Whether that's the nuance the OP was looking for, I can't say.  (When people say things like "What is the address of it", when it seems they probably mean "What is the address in it",  I always suspect their understanding of pointers is significantly incomplete, and that a fair amount of education will be required before they'll be able to properly understand any answer.)

Comment: @ikegami: C 2018 6.2.4 2 explicitly states “… The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.” This means that if the memory that `what` is pointing to is freed, the value of `what` is indeterminate. And if `test_free` is pointing to the same memory, its value also becomes indeterminate.

Comment: Re “I already mentioned there are things you can no longer do with the pointer”: Yes, your answer states “… it becomes undefined behaviour to deference either one.” But that is not all. You can no longer rely on the value of the variable. The C standard permits `printf(%p\n", test_free); free_hash(what); printf("%p\n", test_free);` to print two different values. It would also allow `test_free`, as in `if (test_free)…`, to evaluate as true or as false.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil,. Yes, but irrelevant. You could swap any of those vars for the other and get the same result. (Or not. But again, not relevant.)

Comment: It is on topic because the question asks “What happens to a pointer after what it's been pointing to has been freed” and the statement in this answer that “Nothing happens to either variable once you free that to which they point” is not assured by the C standard. After `free(what)`, the compiler may reuse the memory of `what` and of `test_free` for other purposes, as lifetime-analysis and optimization software will do routinely (“lifetime” in the sense of lifetimes of values in the flow analysis internal the compiler, not in the C standard’s lifetimes of objects.)…

Comment: … So things may happen to `what` and `test_free`; their values and even the bytes that represent them could appear to change after the `free(what)` and before the nominal ends of their lifetimes.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil, The answer is that both vars are in the same boat. Which is what the question truly asks about. What happens if one uses the vars when one shouldn't is not pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.2.4 2 says “… The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.” When you release memory with `free`, the lifetime of any objects in it end, so any pointers to this memory become indeterminate. “Indeterminate” means the pointer value is not even fixed; it may act as if it has a different value each time it is used.

This rule exists because there have been C implementations in which maintaining pointers required auxiliary information associated with the allocated memory. So the “value” of a pointer was not represented just by the bits directly in the memory used for the pointer object itself. Once the memory, and its auxiliary information, are released, it might no longer be possible to interpret the value of the pointer correctly.

In most modern C implementations, addresses are implemented simply as numbers in a “flat” address space. In this case, no auxiliary information is needed to interpret the value of a pointer or to work with it as by adding offsets to it. However, because the rule exists, optimizers in compilers may treat any pointer to freed memory as indeterminate.

For example, in this code:

```
void *x;
free(p);
if (SomeTest)
    x = p;
else
    x = q;
printf("%p\n", x);
```

the compiler is allowed to optimize this to:

```
void *x;
free(p);
x = q;
printf("%p\n", x);
```

even if `SomeTest` is true. That is the fact that `p` is indeterminate after `free` means it is allowed to have any value, so it could have the value of `q`, so the `if` statement would just be:

```
if (SomeTest)
    x = q;
else
    x = q;
```

which of course can be optimized to `x = q;`.

In short, once you release memory, the C standard does not give you any assurance your program will behave as if a pointer to that memory has any particular value. It may act as if the pointer has a different value each time the program uses it.